# Google Mobile-Friendly Test - strange statement

Tags: mobile, robots.txt

When testing my very first training website project in Google Mobile-Friendly Test I get a strange statement claiming that the requested URL is marked as not allowed. (I am not quoting it as it is not in the English language.)

It is strange as there is no robots.txt file in my project.

I'll be grateful for any help.

PS: Here is a link to the Google tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Comment: Are there any meta entries in the `<head>` of your site such as:

    `<meta name="robots" content="noindex"> `

If so, that may stop robots from indexing the page.

Could you post the original message (even though it's in another language), and the URL that is causing the failure? That will help isolate the problem.

Comment: I this question is off-topic. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com